# Как сразу получать stdout в paramiko

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
import paramiko as pk
ssh = pk.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pk.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("hostname", username="username", password="**********")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd my_path ; ./my_script.sh",) # Пробовал с get_pty=True
print stdout.read().decode()
```

Я подключаюсь к lunux хосту и выполняю скрипт my_script.sh. Он выполняется достаточно долго и stdout я получаю уже только после его выполнения.
Вопрос: как получать stdout сразу, не дожидаясь выполнения всего скрипта?
Python 2.7

Comment: `for line in stdout: ...` по строкам например

Comment: @andreymal Я понимаю как получить sdout после окончания работы my_script.sh. Как получить sdout когда скрипт еще работает?

Comment: Если вас не устроил вариант из первого комментария, то как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: Не знаю, что-то такое, чтобы сразу можно было получить весь вывод на данный момент.

Answer (score 1):

После выполнения

```
ssh.exec_command("cd my_path ; ./my_script.sh",)
```

к `stdout` сразу же привязывается объект, с которым вы можете работать как с файлом. Можно считать, что как только скрипт на той стороне что-то выводит, то это сразу же попадает в этот объект. Проблема в том, что вызывается `read()`, а он ждет, пока не будет получен весь вывод скрипта. Нужно читать частями, например, если вывод построчный, то вполне подойдет вариант:

```
for line in stdout
```